# Time complexity using recursion tree method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

I've been trying to solve the given problem using recursion tree method but my answer has not been coming of the same form

T(n)=8T(n/2)+n^2

The answer of the given problem is Theta(n^3)

Comment: which method your using to solved this problem.

Comment: using recursion tree method I divide it into branches and then I get n/2^k=1 which gives me k=logk(n). Then I find the sum of the given costs but I'm not getting n^3

Comment: Naman, given this is a second low quality question today, it looks like you feel the SO is a free tutoring service. It is not. You really have to show what you've already done and how exactly "_answer has not been coming of the same form_". Then we can point to a mistake. Just pasting a question without any other efforts is bad for learning and is not how the SO works.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the lack of working provided by me, I'll keep it in mind. Thanks a lot for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to expand the equation:

```
T(n) = 8 T(n/2) + n^2
T(n) = 8(8T(n/4) +(n/2)^2) + n^2 = 8^2T(n/4) + n^2 + 8 (n/2)^2
T(n) = 8^3T(n/8) + n^2 + 8 (n/2)^2 + 8^2 (n/4)^2
```

Now you can generalize the above sum:

```
T(n) = sum 8^(i) (n/2^i)^2 for i from 0 to log(n)
```

Simplify:

```
T(n) = sum 2^(3i) n^2/2^(2i) for i from 0 to log(n)
T(n) = sum 2^i n^2 for i from 0 to log(n)
T(n) = n^2 (sum 2^i for i from 0 to log(n))
T(n) = n^2 * (2^(log(n)+1) - 1) = n^2 * (2n - 1) = Theta(n^3)
```

In the above, you should be aware that `sum 2^i for i from 0 to log(n)` is `1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(log(n)) = 2^(log(n) + 1) - 1 = 2n - 1`.

Comment: Given the nature of the questions asked by Naman, he is still at the stage leading to learning the Master Theorem so I don't think this answer is really useful to him.